# What's the difference between Phage DNA and Recombinant DNA

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, dna, molecular-genetics

Genetic engineering:
In my textbook the following sentences describe the two, but to me they seem the same:

- The new combination of bases in the DNA (vector DNA + DNA fragment) 
  is called **recombinant DNA**.
- With bacteriophage vector, the bacteriophage will infect the bacteria by injecting its DNA into it. **The Phage DNA** (with the
  desired gene in it) then integrate into the bacterial DNA.

Without going too much into it. What is the difference between Phage DNA and recombinant DNA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Phage DNA** is the DNA in a bacteriophage.

**Recombinant DNA** is synthetically combined DNA used in genetic engineering.

In your case, since the phage's DNA is used as a vector, the phage DNA *is* the recombinant DNA, but that does not mean every phage's DNA is recombinant, since phages occur naturally. The point is, the phage DNA was altered to *become* recombinant DNA.